# Dealing with foreign characters in django query

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I am building a search of city names imported from GeoNames.com. Some of the cities have international characters in the name. For example, "Istanbul" is actually "İstanbul" in the database.

When people search for "Istanbul", İstanbul doesn't come up.

Is there a way I can add a filter or decoder to the search that would know that İstanbul = Istanbul

Currently, it's:

```
cities = City.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
```

Comment: When you say "currently, it's", do you mean, "Currently, the search operation is implemented by this code:"?

Comment: What behaviour do you want? Do you want to let unaccented Latin letters match accented Latin letters?  Do you want transliteration (e.g. a search for Japanese「イスタンブル」) to work? What about misspelling?  Do you care in what order the search results are returned?

Comment: What is your database collation and your connection collation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) will help you solve a certain form of this problem. Unidecode will translate the non-ascii characters to ascii, for example:

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(u"İstanbul")
'Istanbul'
```

You can achieve a similar effect by decomposing the unicode characters and removing the combining diacritics. The problem with this technique is that certain characters **are not decomposable**. So, while "ö" will decompose to an "o" and an umlaut, "Ł" (L-stroke) will stay the same. Unidecode successfully translates "Ł" to "L".

But Undeicode doesn't solve all your problems; cities can be known by different names, or these names can be written differently. For example, in the US we call the capital of China "Beijing", but we used to call it "Peking" (and it's still called "Peking" in Swedish), and translating its name with `unidecode` gives us something else:

```
>>> unidecode(u"\u5317\u4EB0")
'Bei Jing '
```

The best solution is to have a language-specific list of names and not to use the city's actual name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is something ready for it in django.

I would create a separate column in database called something like NameCombinations where I'd put all possible combinations, e.g.  Istanbulİstanbul and would query

```
cities = City.objects.filter(NameCombinations__icontains=query)
```

Comment: I agree your best bet is to maintain a list of alternate spellings.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give definitive advice without more information about what behaviour you want.

However, one obvious step is to define a canonical form for each name (lower case, no accents, etc.), and store the canonical form of the name in a second column of the database, in addition to the correct name.  Then map the search string to the canonical form as well.  Thus, "istanbul" could be the canonical form of "İstanbul".

Another obvious step is to separate the city name into a separate table from the rest of the information about the city.  This lets each city have several names, ie synonyms. Then, for each city name, define as many synonyms as needed to catch different spellings your users favour.  For instance, you could enter "Istanbul" and "イスタンブル" as synonyms of "İstanbul".

You can of course use both of these approaches together.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have set an appropriate collation in the database, the comparison will do exactly as you want.