# remove all non-ASCII from string

Tags: unicode, ascii, filenames, transliteration, truncation

My question is general - I want to ask if there is any special modules in programming languages or a ready program which will allow me to accomplish my task.

Is there any convenient way (other than writing own functions with multiple replace statement) to automatically substitute all national characters to corespondents letters? For example, I want to substitute *æ* to *ae*, *ä* to *a*, *ę* to *e* and so on.

If it's impossible to prepare universal function, is there any ready function in currently used programming languages, which will remove such characters simply by limiting allowed char only to those from standard Latin alphabet?

Comment: This needs more detailed information. What platform and filesystem are you on? And why do you want to do this in the first place - what problems are you encountering with these special characters?

Comment: The usual question: Why do you want to do that? You loose information, as 'corresponding' ASCII letters might be a silly concept for some locales. Especially for filenames there are basically only two things that make sense: UTF-16 for Windows, UTF-8 for Unices. Everything else is a total mess to use in one way or the other.

Comment: **The standard Latin alphabet has about 600 characters in it,** you know. I have to echo the query from @schlenk — why in the world would you want to do this wicked wicked thing? The cultural narrowness is breathtakingly primitive.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to use only letters which I can see on my keyboard. Answer to question is quite simple - I use system which crash when operate on files containing some special characters in their file names.

Answer (score 2):

There is [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode), which is available for several languages (perl, python, java). I've previous written about it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968914/320220).

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(u"İstanbul")
'Istanbul'
>>> unidecode(u"\u5317\u4EB0")
'Bei Jing '
```

Answer (score 1):

Transliteration is the word you're looking for :)

In php, that is achieved through iconv:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

As others have said, it's probably best to keep everything in Unicode (utf8 or 16) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I do not now what language you are using but in php you can do

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $text);
```

you can change the reg exp to allow more/less characters.

Comment: That makes strings containing umlauts etc. pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can scan the files in a directory:

```
<?php
$dir = '';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file[0] == '.' || is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {
            continue;
        }
//functions here
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Then rename them all with this regex:

```
$newname = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $oldname);
```

You would set $oldname to the filename of each file in the directory, and have it where `//functions` is, which would go through each file in the directory and rename it according to the regex.

Comment: Then you will have a blank filename, and you can set an if-then statement, or do this: `pat = array('e' => '[eéèêë]','n' => '[nñ]','o' => '[oòóôõö]','a' => '[aàáâãäå]','i' => '[iìíîï]','u' => '[uùúûü]','y' => '[yýÿ]');` and `preg_replace("/".$pat['e']."/i",'#',$string);` I remember seeing how to do this with Cyrillic chars, and am trying to locate the site where it was. EDIT -  Here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=X1NAsnrJ

Answer (score 0):

If your input is Unicode, you can apply the [Unicode normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) NKFD to approximate what you want. Python has this [built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). After normalization, you can strip the accents, which will have been separated from the letters they belong to.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> s = u"äçéì"  # u"" makes a Unicode string in Python 2.x
>>> unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", s).encode("ascii", errors="ignore")
'acei'
```

This won't work for æ, though.